# Emmet sublime text package doesnt work with angular project

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2, emmet

I just started using ANgularJS and Ionic. I was using Emmet package with sublime Text for Html autocompletion. 
I have just started my angular/ionic project and I notice emmet is not working for my html file. For example index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" >
    <title ></title >

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css"
          rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="css/style.css"
          rel="stylesheet" >

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js" ></script >

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js" ></script >

<script src="js/patch.js" ></script >
    <script src="js/app.js" ></script >
</head >
<body ng-app="soundboard" >
<ion-pane ng-controller="SoundBoardCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized" >
        <h1 class="title" >Soundboard</h1 >
    </ion-header-bar >
    <ion-content >
        <ion-list show-delete="model.showDelete" show-reorder="model.showMove">
      <ion-item  ng-click="play(sound)" ng-repeat="sound in model.sounds" class=" item-avatar item-icon-right" >
        <img ng-src="{{sound.image}}"/>
        <h2>{{sound.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{sound.desc}} </p>
        <i class="icon ion-volume-high"></i>
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"></ion-delete-button>
        <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon"></ion-reorder-button>
      </ion-item>
        </ion-list >
    </ion-content >
</ion-pane >
</body >
</html >
```

Why is that so ? Shouldnt Emmet detect this is an html file ?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently switched to Sublime Text 3 (beta) *after* starting to use Ionic, and have been using the Emmet plugin successfully with Ionic markup in HTML files, with the exception of some markup inside an Angular template: `<script type="text/ng-template">`.  I change these to `<div type="text/ng-template">` while editing with Emmet, then change them to script tags when I'm done.  I suggest you give this a try - the one thing to be mindful of is some of your ST2 plugins may not be available in ST3.